# When to know it's time to replace the Nexus One battery?

Tags: nexus-one, battery, battery-life

As we all know, battery consumption rate (i.e. "per hour") is not very standardized and its highly dependent on actual use, per user.

This makes it very difficult for me to know whether I need a new battery for my Nexus One (I bought it used) or not.

Assuming WiFi and Bluetooth are enabled, how long should the Nexus One battery last while the Nexus One is in **Standby**?

How long should the battery last when the Nexus One is **completely turned off**?

Thanks.

Comment: If you're leaving wifi **and** bluetooth on constantly, then I'd expect short standby battery life, no matter how new your battery is!

Comment: @GAThrawn Thanks. What you are saying makes sense, but how short is "short"? 1-hour? 12-hours? 24-hours? Other?

Comment: you know it's time to replace your phone's battery when it regularly cannot survive your typical day. A "typical day" might be extremely different for every people, for example, I almost always have a USB cable and my laptop with me so I can charge almost anywhere. It does not matter if the battery is short-lived if you're mostly at home, car, and work and you have (wall/car) charger everywhere. More precisely, you know you need to replace your battery if you regularly drained your battery in a situation where you are unable or unwilling to charge.

Comment: @Lie Ryan My typical day requires the phone to go without recharge (while in `standby`, WiFi+BT enabled) for 24 hours. My current battery doesn't meet this requirement. Will a new battery do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is very difficult to put a number on the estimated battery life of the N1, mainly because there isn't really a standard "typical use".

But since it seems that you are looking for a number, [this thread](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/android/thread?tid=2eb4a163b4e3a6ff&hl=en) may help.

Since at least 2 people reported at least 2 days in a single charge (given certain conditions), I would say that if your N1 battery doesn't hold more than 10 hours, it is time to start shopping for a new battery.